# await and LINQ within DBContext

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, async-await, entity-framework-6

We have a service layer in our application which is composed of three logical layers - web service, business model services (our name for the layer that executes business logic and orchestrates calls to various repositories), and the repository layer which connects to various DBs using EF6.

Many of our repository calls just get data straight from DB sets via ToListAsync, FirstOrDefaultAsync, like this:

```
public async Task<MyObject> GetSomeData()
{
    using(var context = new myDBContext())
    {
        return await context.SomeDbSet.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.Something == true);  
    }
}
```

We're having a bit of an internal debate as to whether using await here is the right thing to do or not, because there is nothing executing in this method after the await.  I/we understand that the way the code is written, it is a necessity otherwise the context would be disposed of as soon as the method exists and it would result in an exception.  But if we await here, we have to await all the way up (or down, depending on how you look at it) our call stack, and that would result in a number of expensive and somewhat unnecessary context switches.

The other option here is to make the repository methods synchronous, and do a `Task.Run()` in the method that calls the repository method, like:

```
Task.Run(() => MyRepository.GetSomeData());
```

we can then await this call if we want, or just return the task object again to the caller.  The downside here is the call to the database then becomes synchronous and one thread from the pool is blocking for the entire length of the database call.

So this comes down to what's more expensive?  Unnecessary context switches via await or having threads block?  It seems that there is no right answer, but is there a best practice?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: If you chain ConfigureAwait(false) to your async calls there won't be a context switch.

Comment: There won't be a context switch upon completion of the task but that might be desired and required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should, of course, use the async version.

As you said, if you don't `await` you will dispose of the context before the operation completed, but that doesn't mean the calling methods need to use async-await as well. They can return the task just as you mention in the `Task.Run` option:

```
public Task<MyObject> FooAsync()
{
    // do some stuff

    return GetSomeDataAsync();
}

public async Task<MyObject> GetSomeDataAsync()
{
    using(var context = new myDBContext())
    {
        return await context.SomeDbSet.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.Something == true);  
    }
}
```

You mentioned that the cost in this case is some expensive context switches. I'm not sure what you mean by that, but if you're referring to thread context switches then there's only a single one. The calling thread will be released while awaiting the asynchronous operation and a different thread will continue running when that operation completes.

Not only that this is negligible compared to the time it takes to execute the actual operation, if you use `Task.Run` you have the same context switch as a blocked thread is taken out of the CPU.

Using `Task.Run` on a synchronous operation is redundant. It's just blocking a thread and it potentially requires more context switches then the async equivalent.

Comment: I think that part we were missing is the fact that you don't have to await all the way up the call stack.  We thought if a method was async you had to await it, which meant that we would have 3 awaits up the entire stack, which we considered to be expensive since each one would result in a context switch at some point.  I think your suggestion is good for us, thanks!

Comment: @jeff.eynon Even if you would have used async-await 3 methods deep there will still only be a single context-switch at most.

Comment: Should that call to FirstOrDefault actually be FirstOrDefaultAsync?  FirstOrDefault doesn't return a Task and cannot be awaited.

Answer (score 0):

There are many kinds of “context” in the .NET Framework: LogicalCallContext, SynchronizationContext, HostExecutionContext, SecurityContext, ExecutionContext etc.. SynchronizationContext is captured when using Async/Await, but it is no the only context that get captured. Along with SynchronizationContext, ExecutionContext also get captured. ExecutionContext consist of SecurityContext, LogicalCallContext etc..

An async code is always executed against the captured ExecutionContext. When an await complete, if there was a current SynchronizationContext that got captured, the continuation representing the remainder of the asynchronous method is posted to that SynchronizationContext.

So when executing code under Task.Run, it's only the SynchronizationContext that will no get captured, but ExecutionContext will still get captured in any case. You can get same behaviour of not getting SynchronizationContext captured by async/await using ConfigureAwait(false) when awaiting. The down side is that when await completes, the SynchronizationContext will be ignored and the Framework will attempt to continue the execution wherever the previous asynchronous operation completed, which is what you exactly want.

So in your scenarios I think you should be using async/await with ConfigureAwait(false), as there would not be any overhead of SynchronizationContext in this case and at the same time there would be no overhead of blocking any thread.

The following post may be helpful to get more insight: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx